# Adding two integers from two different strings

Tags: php, include, sum, addition

Let's say I want to include 2 text-files like this (the variables are paths):

```
<?php
include($ingredientsFirst);
include($ingredientsSecond);
?>

$ingredientsFirst (.txt-file):

1 Banana<br>
2 Apples<br>

$ingredientsSecond (.txt-file):

3 Banana<br>
4 Apples<br>
```

Is there a function which can sum up these ingredients from two different files and then output them like this:

```
4 Banana<br>
6 Apples<br>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you would have to read the files, extract the number and the value then do the math - include is not going to get you anywhere

Comment: if this is a big part of what ever project this is, you should consider using a better data structure such as a database.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing built in, but I think you could handle this with some arrays. I would use the ingredients as a key and quantity as the value. For example something like this:

```
<?php
function combine_ingredients($files_array)
{
    $res = array();
    foreach( $file_array as $file ){
       //Open each file
       $file_r = fopen($file, 'r');
       while( ($line = fgets($file_r)) !== FALSE ){ 
           $parts = explode(' ', $line);
           //Grab the number of an ingredients 
           $quantity = intval(array_shift($parts));
           $key = implode(" ", $parts);
           //Have I seen this ingredient already
           if( isset($res[$key]) )
               $res[$key] += $quantity;
           else
               $res[$key] = $quantity;
       }
       //Close the file
       fclose($file_r);
    } 
    return $res;
}

print_r( combine_ingredients(array($ingredientsFirst, $ingredientsSecond)) );
```

There is a lot of errors you can have with data inconsistency, but this can be a good starting point.